# in cosmosDB/MongoDB API sorting by string fields containing numbers with the collation option numericOrdering does not work

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

In cosmosDB MongoDB API I need to run a query to retrieve items sorted by a string field which can also contains numbers, for example item-2, item-3, item-11. From MongoDB documentation the default behavior would be to sort the items like [item-11, item-2, item-3] comparing them as string, however from version 3.4 it is possible to use the collation in this way:

> db.collectionName.find().sort({title: 1}).collation({locale: "en_US",
> **numericOrdering: true**})

to  sort numbers in substrings as numbers (in my case [item-2, item-3, item-11]);

My CosmosDB server version is 3.6 so it should support this as it was added in MongoDB 3.4 but the collation seems to be ignored (tested using Compass).

Is there a way to make this work or some documented reference about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we have indexes set on the fields I was trying to sort by; these indexes were created without collation and, like described in [MongoDB official docs][1]

[1]: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#index-use-and-collation, in order to sort with a collation on an index, the index must have bene created with the same collation.

UPDATE:

even this seems to be a wrong lead, I tried creating an index with collation using:

```
   db.test_documents.createIndex( { title: 1 }, { collation: { locale: "en", numericOrdering: true } } )
```

end I received the error:

```
{
    "message" : "collation",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 115,
    "codeName" : "CommandNotSupported",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

cannot find any reference to collation in Azure CosmosDB documentation either, at this point I think it is not supported.